# configure SSL in Apache Flume JMS 1.6.0

Tags: apache, ssl, flume

I am trying to configure SSL in Apache Flume JMS1.6.0. As part of Apache Flume JMS Source does not support SSL by nature. 
Is Anyone implemented by enabling SSL in Apache Flume JMS1.6.0.
Is there any option in writing custom code to enable SSL for JMS Source

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Flume JMS Source doesn't have this feature. Flume Avro source or HTTP source has this.

https://github.com/apache/flume/blob/trunk/flume-ng-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flume/source/AvroSource.java

You can refer the above class and write a custom JMS Source.